# Adding objects to array list - end up with same values

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Bit of an odd one. I am trying to create a board game (backgammon) and have created an object called piece. On my board I am trying to create an array list of pieces

```
ArrayList<piece> pieces = new ArrayList<piece>();

piece newPiece = new piece(1, 1, "red", "top");
piece newPiece2 = new piece(1, 2, "black", "top");

pieces.add(newPiece);
System.out.println(newPiece.getCol());
pieces.add(newPiece2);
System.out.println(newPiece2.getCol());
```

I was expecting the outputs to be 'red' then 'black', but I actually get 'black' then 'black'? Any suggestions why this might be happening?

Comment: Pretty sure your fields are `static`.

Comment: how is `class piece` implemented

Answer (score 9):

The `ArrayList` is a red-herring here - you're never even fetching the pieces out again. You'll see exactly the same behaviour with just this code:

```
piece newPiece = new piece(1, 1, "red", "top");
piece newPiece2 = new piece(1, 2, "black", "top");
System.out.println(newPiece.getCol());
System.out.println(newPiece2.getCol());
```

I strongly suspect that the bug is in the `piece` class - whatever variable you're using to store the colour is probably a *static* variable instead of an *instance* variable. Static variables are related to the type rather than any specific instance of the type, so if you overwrite the value of a static variable in a constructor, you'll always see that value when you fetch it again. You want different state for each instance, so you should have instance variables.

(Additionally, you should improve your names, e.g. `Piece` instead of `piece`, and `getColor` instead of `getCol`.)

Comment: That was really fast..